# In reactive programming, is the sequence of doOnNext calls guaranteed?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Reactive programming newbie. I have a sequence of calls in my Flux and I need to ensure they're done in order. Eg

```
Flux<Thing> flux = ...
.doOnNext(this::sendThing)
.doOnNext(this::persistThing)
.doOnError(error -> log.error("", error))
.blockLast();
```

I need to ensure that `sendThing` completes before `persistThing`. I'm unclear, being a reactive newbie, if this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> The Consumer is executed **first**, then the onNext signal is propagated
> downstream.

Thus, `this::sendThing` consumer will be completed before the `onNext` signal
be propagated to `this::persistThing`.

Example:

```java
    Flux.range(1, 3)
        .doOnNext(n -> log.info("doOnNext1"))
        .log()
        .doOnNext(n -> log.info("doOnNext2"))
        .blockLast();
```

The above snippet prints the following:

- doOnNext1
- | onNext(1)
- doOnNext2
- doOnNext1
- | onNext(2)
- doOnNext2
- doOnNext1
- | onNext(3)
- doOnNext2

`onNext` signal is always propagated before `"doOnNext2"` is printed.

Bear in mind that **doOn** methods should be used only for side-effect operations(e.g. log).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this reactive implementation, but looks like you're adding two independent subscribers to a single observable, which does not guarantee an order of execution.

If send and persist are blocking (sync) functions you can just create some 'sendAndSync' function.

Otherwise, you need to make the 'send' into and observable itself, and 'persist' should be its subscriber. You can achieve this by 'send' writing to a PublishSubject once a send is completed, and 'persist' being the subscriber (via doOnNext) of that PublishSubject.